# MongoDB: export distinct column value

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Anyone have idea how to export distinct column value on mongodb using **mongoexport** command.

**Command:** db.coll.distinct("uid");

The solution i have tried is :

```
 mongoexport --csv -d db -c collection -q '{distinct: "collection", "key": "uid"}' -f "uid" -o distinctUid.csv
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to do it this way. [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/index.html) is a database command, and `--query` option allows to use only a [query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) to filter documents.

If you are using mongodb v3.4 or later, you can use [views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) to aggregate your collection and export it from the view.

First create the view in mongo shell:

```
db.createView("distinctCollectionUid", "collection", [{ $group: { _id: "$uid"}}]);
```

Then export it:

```
mongoexport -d db -c distinctCollectionUid --type=csv -f "_id" -o distinctUid.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

its working for me.

Example:

First create view:

```
db.createView("distinctCollectionBI2_Style( BI2_Style is  key which value must distinc)","best_seller_data(your collection name)", [{ $group: { _id: "$BI2_Style"}}]);
```

Then export:

```
mongoexport -d best-seller(db name) -c distinctCollectionBI2_Style --type=csv -f "_id" -o Desktop/pretr/style.csv
```