# Pull out all unique values from a huge dataset in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I a have an old MongoDB Standalone archive store that has more than `10 Billion documents` (almost 10 TB of data).

Sample Document:

```
{
    "Key1": "Value 1",
    "Key2": "Value 2",
    "Key3": "Value 3",
    "Key4": "Value 4",
    "Key5": "Value 5",
    "Key6": "Value 6",
    "Key7": "Value 7",
    "Key8": "Value 8",
    "Key9": "Value 9",
}
```

Now what I want to do is pull out all the unique values of `Key6` from the entire dataset. I do have an index on it.

what am I doing:

```
db.myCollection.distinct("key6")
```

But the query seems to take quite long. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this?

Comment: most of the time would be spent on downloading the docs to the client. instead try an aggregation with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage and iterate over the cursor to access the data. or use an [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) stage to create a new collection with the result data.

Comment: The distinct method can use the index on the `key6` field. The `explain` on the method returns a _query plan_ which shows the plan stage: "PROJECTION_COVERED" (indicating it is a covered query).

Comment: It is also correct the using an aggregation query may be a better option. Processing such a huge amount of data requires lots of memory, and aggregation has the option `allowDiskUse` when set to `true` will use the disk when the memory required exceeds the available memory.

Comment: @prasad_ so basically use the aggregate query to pull out the data and then export to a file? Can you help me out with an aggregate query?

Comment: @iam.Carrot so, your requirement is to export the unique values to a file right? if so, have a look at the "--query" option in [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-query).

Comment: @iam.Carrot Please tell what is the version of MongoDB you are working with?

Comment: @prasad_ it's 3.6.14

Comment: In what form do you want the output as? Another collection _or_ an array _or_ a file?

Comment: @prasad_ just a file with top to bottom text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Aggregation:**

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "$key6" } } ], { allowDiskUse: true } )
```

The aggregation returns a *cursor*. To write the output to an array, use the cursor's `.toArray()` method.

To write the output to another (new) collection use the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "$key6" } }, { $out: "newCollection" } ], { allowDiskUse: true } )
```

Note that there is no option to write to a file using aggregation query.

**NOTES:**

(1) [$group Operator and Memory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-operator-and-memory):

> The $group stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if
>   the stage exceeds this limit, $group returns an error. To allow for
>   the handling of large datasets, set the allowDiskUse option to true.
>   This flag enables $group operations to write to temporary files

(2) Also, see [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).

(3) [Return Information on Aggregation Pipeline Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation)

Generate an *query plan* on your aggregation, as follows:

```
db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "$key6" } } ], { allowDiskUse: true } )
```

The plan output is likely to be like this, specifying that the query is a *covered query*:

```
"queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {

        },
        "queryHash" : "69A129B4",
        "planCacheKey" : "69A129B4",
        "winningPlan" : {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
                "transformBy" : {
                        "key6" : 1,
                        "_id" : 0
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "DISTINCT_SCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                                "key6" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "key6_1",
```

Comment: Here is a post about [MongoDB: export distinct column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560326/mongodb-export-distinct-column-value) to a CSV file. This allows write the output to a file (works with MongoDB version 3.4+).

Comment: Perfect. This works like a charm. Best part I don't need to worry about writing to file since I can simply take a dump later. I wonder why it didn't strike me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query efficiency speaking there's not much you can do, with a such a large dataset we can't expect "magic" to happen even if it's a somewhat simple operation.

Now we do want to improve runtime as it's important to you but we have to take a different approach, some options for example:

1. Preprocess your data, create a database of unique `key6` value's, assuming the amount of unique items is significantly smaller than the amount of documents this will boost performance.
2. Rethink architecture? - I have no idea how your data is built, but you usually have options like to shard your data, change your shard key and so on..

Comment: I see people offering `aggregate` as a "faster" option, so no aggregation is actually slower, you do use it instead when you don't have enough memory and combined with the `allowDiskUse` flag it can handle it as it saves results in disk.